# Grab specific user data from class using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  /*
  var $body = $('body');
  $body.html('');
  */

  //current feed
  var index = streams.home.length - 1;
  while (index >= 0) {
    var tweet = streams.home[index];
    //need to separate tweet message so only user class can be used for click event
    var $tweet = $('<div class=tweet></div>');
    var $user = $('<p id=users></p>');
    var $message = $('<p id=message></p>');
    var $time = $('<p id=time></p>');

    $time.text(tweet.created_at).appendTo($tweet);
    $user.text('@' + tweet.user + ': ').appendTo($tweet);
    $message.text(tweet.message).appendTo($tweet);
    $tweet.appendTo($('#tweets'));

    index -= 1;
  }

  //click event for new tweets
  $('button').click(function() {
    //pull a random tweet from streams.home which is an array of all tweets
    //can reuse code from current feed
    var tweet = streams.home[Math.floor(Math.random() * streams.home.length)];
    var $tweet = $('<div class=tweet></div>');
    var $user = $('<p id=users></p>');
    var $message = $('<p id=message></p>');
    var $time = $('<p id=time></p>');

    $time.text(tweet.created_at).appendTo($tweet);
    $user.text('@' + tweet.user + ': ').appendTo($tweet);
    $message.text(tweet.message).appendTo($tweet);
    $tweet.appendTo($('#tweets'));
  })

  //be able to view user profile
  //click event on user data only
  $('#tweets').on('click', '#users', function() {
    $('.container').hide();
  })

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <h1> Twiddler </h1>
  <h3> Social Feed </h3>
</header>
<div class='container'>
  <section>
    <button id='home'> Home </button>
    <section class='main'>
      <p id='tweets'></p>
      <button id='new'>Push</button>
    </section>
  </section>
</div>
<div class='userfeed'>
</div>
```

I'm making a Twitter look a like website as a project. I am working on a function to view a specific users history. Basically clicking on the name of the user would display their history and hide every other user. I'm not sure how to go about this and grab the data for specific users. What kind of jQuery functions should I be using to accomplish this?

Comment: anyone? :(........

Comment: Your question makes no sense with the provided code. It's really hard to understand what you want and where you're stuck at. What is `streams`? Where are the other users? .. what?

Comment: There is a separate JS file that is not shown here. It has several functions and objects but I didn't feel like it was pertinent to include here. Streams is an object that holds data regarding username, message, time of all their posts. Apologies for the ambiguous question as I am just starting to learn jquery and I'm not sure how to ask my question. This image is my current HTML page: https://imgur.com/a/03cqG24. Basically, what I am trying to do is if I click on let's say `@sharksforcheap` then I want to display only his  tweets on the HTML page and exclude anyone else.

Comment: I have the click event down for clicking on different usernames. The problem I have is being able to take that click value which would be the username and then being able to display only their tweets. Essentially a filter or profile for that specific click

Comment: Post an JSON example of that response... create a [mcve] - Please [edit] your Question, add all the necessary to make it understandable.

Comment: Stop using duplicated IDs. ID means **Identifier** and inside a single document there should be only one.

Answer (score 0):

- To filter an array use Array.prototype.filter()
- Create a templating function for a single Tweet that returns the desired HTML markup
- Don't use duplicated IDs, use classes instead
- On click retrieve the `data-user` value and filter the Array of objects by `user` property

```js
const tweets = [
  {created_at: "2020-03-14T08:15:30Z", user:"aaa", message:"Lorem aaa ipsum"},
  {created_at: "2020-03-15T08:16:21Z", user:"bbb", message:"Lorem bbb ipsum"},
  {created_at: "2020-03-16T08:17:45Z", user:"aaa", message:"Lorem aaa ipsum"},
  {created_at: "2020-03-16T08:19:10Z", user:"ccc", message:"Lorem ccc ipsum"},
];

const template_tweet = tweet => $("<div>", {
  class: "tweet",
  html: `
    <span class="tweet-time">${new Date(tweet.created_at).toLocaleString()}</span>
    <a class="tweet-user" data-user="${tweet.user}">@${tweet.user}</a>
    <div class="tweet-message">${tweet.message}</div>
  `,
});

const showTweets = (tweets, user) => {
  const tweetsFiltered = user ? tweets.filter(tweet => tweet.user === user) : tweets;
  $("#tweets").html(tweetsFiltered.map(template_tweet));
}

showTweets(tweets); // Show all unfiltered

$("#tweets").on('click', '[data-user]', function() {
  showTweets(tweets, this.dataset.user); // Show by user name
});
```

```css
.tweet {padding: 10px;}
.tweet-user {color:#08e; cursor:pointer;}
```

```html
<div id="tweets"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```